# Creating installer for Mac OS X from a C++ application

Tags: c++, macos, installation

I have created an application in C++ using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers on Mac OS X.
My application includes external libraries like: `PortAudio`, `Aubio` and `wxWidgets` (dynamic linking).

How can I create an installer, so the application can be installed on Mac OS X computers?

Comment: Well, it depends if your application needs to be linked with dynamic libs that are not available by default on OS X. Is it the case?

Comment: @xiaomao I don't think such a comment is useful...

Comment: @Macmade I would think there are tons of tutorials and documents online explaining. I wouldn't think it's a good idea to mirror everything here.

Comment: @xiaomao Not a good place to argue, but I personally think the question is valid and on-topic, even if we don't know if the op did a Google search before posting it. If you disagree with that, flag the question, so moderators can review it, or simply provide links, if you can easily find related answers on Google.

Comment: I wouldnt bother asking for help if i didnt google first. My application needs to be linked with dynamic libs!

Comment: @user1695716 Since you've got dylib dependancies, this is more complicated, as you will need to provide those libs with your installer...

Answer (score 2):

You are not the first person to experience this issue(not surprising):
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/porting/conceptual/portingunix/intro/intro.html

Specifically installers:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/porting/conceptual/portingunix/distributing/distibuting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002855-TPXREF101

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Overview/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005371-CH3-SW2

Comment: Thank you, your second link lead me to this one: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're developing something that will live in /Applications/MyApp.app.

Unless you actually *want* to clutter up the user's system with a random assortment of libraries, **you don't**. OSX doesn't have package management like you might be used to on other *nixes; the only reason to install dynamic libraries/frameworks is if you are the official distributor of the framework (and can guarantee sensible versioning, backwards compatibility, and hopefully no collisions with others' packages) or if you have a suite of apps and want to reuce install bloat (e.g. StuffIt). But these things can never be uninstalled!

The more usual thing to do is to embed libraries in the .app bundle, e.g. in Contents/MacOS, Contents/usr/lib, Contents/Frameworks, or whatever. The exact path doesn't really matter (I'd be tempted to use Contents/MacOS for simplicity). You then use access the libraries using relative paths — [@executable_path, @load_path, or @rpath](https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath), which generally involves tweaking the libraries you build with [install-name-tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/install-name-tool). IIRC, Adium, Audacity, and Firefox all do this, along with (probably) many many more.

I can't recall a tutorial off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you very much, even though i'm a noob i at least managed to understand what i have to do. Hope it works!

Comment: After a lot of studying i managed to accomplish doing all of the above. I'm including two photos, one from the bundle and one from the results i got from MacDependency. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtsu9ers7gr26a5 /Screen%20shot%202012-09-28%20at%204.58.10%20AM.png https://www.dropbox.com/s/5pgu08epc532qbf/Screen%20shot%202012-09-28%20at%204.56.15%20AM.png I managed to successfully run the application in my computer having changed the paths of the libraries but when i tried launching it on another Mac it just didn't start. I'm frustrated :/

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtsu9ers7gr26a5/Screen%20shot%202012-09-28%20at%204.58.10%20AM.png

Comment: @user1695716" I just get 404s.